# OSX: gpg command error, dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: linux, macos, gnupg, homebrew, rvm

After I migrating my MacBook, I found out I miss the command `gpg`.

And it threw this error when I wanted to install `rvm`

```
⋊> ~ gpg                                                                15:39:34
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gpg
  Reason: image not found
fish: 'gpg' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

I have tried the following way to fix it, but none of them works.

```
brew upgrade gnupg
brew unlink gnupg
brew link gnupg
```

Furthermore, I don't have this folder `/usr/local/opt/gettext/.`

Did I need to install something to fix this issue?

### Update

I put the output of `brew doctor` here

https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/fae106018447e868d64ff1a9d3e6266a

Comment: I download the latest version of `GPG` (https://gpgtools.org/), and it works.

Comment: How did you install it, not via brew?

Comment: @tink By above link, https://releases.gpgtools.org/GPG_Suite-2018.3.dmg

Comment: Cheers. I went down a slightly more complex path; unlinking things and re-installing via brew ... also worked in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somehow you are missing `gettext` from brew.  Since you mentioned you are migrating, it seems that perhaps you only partially migrated things that were in `/usr/local` .   There may be other libraries/binaries/etc that are missing.

Try starting with `brew install gettext` and see where that gets you.